# C++ Strange Behavior Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, defined

This code outputs T2, T4 for Visual Studio 2012 and 2008 and T1,T2,T3,T4 for gcc. 
What's the reason?

```
#include <iostream>

#define ABC

#define T1 defined(ABC)

#define T2 defined( ABC )

#define T3 defined(ABC )

#define T4 defined( ABC)


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

#if T1

    std::cout<<"T1"<<std::endl;
#endif


#if T2

    std::cout<<"T2"<<std::endl;
#endif


#if T3

    std::cout<<"T3"<<std::endl;
#endif


#if T4

    std::cout<<"T4"<<std::endl;
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And why couldn't you use the live preview to check that your post looks OK?

Comment: Didn't find how to escape sharp symbol.

Comment: Run both compilers with the keep pre-processed option and have a look at what they output

Comment: hm, in vs2013 i'm getting only T2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [conditional directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd.aspx) page. I've found that:

> The defined directive can be used in an #if and an #elif directive,
>   but nowhere else.

Changing your code to:

```
#include <iostream>

#define ABC

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

#if defined(ABC)
    std::cout << "T1" << std::endl;
#endif


#if defined( ABC )
    std::cout << "T2" << std::endl;
#endif


#if defined(ABC )
    std::cout << "T3" << std::endl;
#endif


#if defined( ABC)
    std::cout << "T4" << std::endl;
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Will produce `T1,T2,T3,T4` output in VS 2013

Comment: From this description: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/conditional it turns out that "defined" processing goes before macro expansion, and macro expansion goes before expression evaluation. Does it mean that "defined" within an expanded macro is an undefined behaviour and it may result in anything, including substituting whole "defined" call with 0, syntax error or whatever? Aren't there any known issues about that?

Comment: Found it: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Defined.html - it's really stated as undefined behaviour